# How do I access this Javascript property?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, sinon

I need to make sure that a certain method inside the below shown `UserMock`-class was called. I've created this mock version to inject into another module to prevent default behaviour during testing.

I am already using `sinon.js`, so how can I access a method such as `isValid()` and replace it with a spy/stub? Is it possible to do this without instantiating the class?

```
var UserMock = (function() {
  var User;
  User = function() {};
  User.prototype.isValid = function() {};
  return User;
})();
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var UserMock = (function() {
  var User;
  User = function() {};
  User.prototype.isValid = function() {};
  return User;
})();
```

---

Simply via `prototype`:

```
(function(_old) {
    UserMock.prototype.isValid = function() {
        // my spy stuff
        return _old.apply(this, arguments); // Make sure to call the old method without anyone noticing 
    }
})(UserMock.prototype.isValid);
```

---

**Explanation:**

```
(function(_old) {
```

and

```
})(UserMock.prototype.isValid);
```

Makes a reference to the method `isValue` to the variable `_old`. The closure is made so we don't pulede the parent scope with the variable.

```
UserMock.prototype.isValid = function() {
```

Redeclares the prototype method

```
return _old.apply(this, arguments); // Make sure to call the old method without anyone noticing
```

Calling the old method and returning the result from it.

Using apply lets put in the right scope (`this`) with all the arguments passed to the function
Eg. if we make a simple function and apply it.

```
function a(a, b, c) {
   console.log(this, a, b, c);
}

//a.apply(scope, args[]);
a.apply({a: 1}, [1, 2, 3]);

a(); // {a: 1}, 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: you forgot to return the result.

Comment: Would you mind telling me where I could find an explanation on how this works - I've never seen this syntax before

Comment: @Industrial Ignore the `return the result.` part.