# Can I overwrite a constructor in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I just learned that I [can overwrite a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13383345/how-do-i-access-this-javascript-property) in a Javascript class, as shown below, but what about the actual constructor?

If possible, how do I do it without instantiating the class?

```
var UserModel = (function() {
  var User;
  User = function() {}; // <- I want to overwrite this whilst keeping below methods
  User.prototype.isValid = function() {};
  return User;
})();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just temporarily save the `prototype` object, and then replace the constructor function:

```
var proto = UserModel.prototype;
UserModel = function () { /* new implementation */ };
UserModel.prototype = proto;
```

Comment: Note that you will not be able to overwrite a constructor if you don't have access to the scope .. What is the use case ?

Comment: @MaëlNison I think OP wants to overwrite the constructor subsequently.

Comment: @MaëlNison For testing purposes to be able to inject spies to catch arguments for validation

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you create a temporary function which does nothing, you set its prototype has the prototype of the parent class, then you can use the base class as parent without calling its constructor.

If you need to reference the constructor of your parent class from the constructor of the child class, you juste have to use `Function.prototype.apply` to forward the constructor call.

Javascript inheritance model :

```
// Base class

var Base = function ( ) {
    this.foo = 40;
};

Base.prototype.bar = function ( ) {
    return this.foo;
};

// Inherited class

var Child = function ( ) {
    Base.apply( this, arguments );
    this.foo += 2;
};

var F = function ( ) { };
F.prototype = Base.prototype;
Child.prototype = new F( );
```

Comment: Why do you do Child.prototype = new F( ); and not Child.prototype = Base.prototype; ?

Comment: @Naor Because if you just set the prototype as being the prototype of the parent, if you add new methods to the prototype of the child, they will be added to the parent too. And if you overwrite parent methods in the child prototype, they will be replaced in the parent too (because they're the same object). The point of using `new` is that it will create a new instance separated which can be edited without mutating the original prototype.